# select the children with only some elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select children of some elements and reject other elements.

please refer below HTML.

```
    <g id="container_svg_SeriesGroup_0" transform="translate(77,465)">
    <defs>
<linearGradient id="container_svg_symbol0Gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="600%"><stop offset="0" stop-color="gray" stop-opacity="1"/><stop offset="0.5" stop-color="blue" stop-opacity="1"/>
</linearGradient>
</defs>
<path id="container_svg_rectsymbol0" fill="url(#container_svg_symbol0Gradient)" stroke-width="1" stroke="Gray" d="M -5 -450 L 5 -450 L 5 -440 L -5 -440 L -5 -450"/>
<defs>
<linearGradient id="container_svg_symbol1Gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="600%"><stop offset="0" stop-color="gray" stop-opacity="1"/><stop offset="0.5" stop-color="blue" stop-opacity="1"/></linearGradient>
</defs>
<path id="container_svg_rectsymbol1" fill="url(#container_svg_symbol1Gradient)" stroke-width="1" stroke="Gray" d="M 73.1111111111111 -71.75 L 83.1111111111111 -71.75 L 83.1111111111111 -61.75 L 73.1111111111111 -61.75 L 73.1111111111111 -71.75" transform="scale(1)"/>
...................
</g>
```

i want to select children of this group "container_svg_SeriesGroup_0" but not selecting "defs" group. i want to find the other elements instead of "defs"

i tried like below

```
$("#container_svg_SeriesGroup_0").children("path")
```

it returns path element. but in My DOM any kind of elements will be placed in this  group"container_svg_SeriesGroup_0"

so i just not select "defs" group and select other elements direct children of that group.

expecting answer like using ".not" selector in jquery.

Thanks,

Siva

Comment: Are you sure `children` is what you want and not `find`?

Comment: "find" is also returns the element but i don't want to select "defs" group. i just need all elements other than "defs" group

Comment: Try with the `not` or `filter` methods to narrow down your collection.

Comment: i found the solution $(this.chartObj.gSymbolGroupEle).children().not("defs"). whether "find" will work for this

Comment: @eclanrs: may i know the exact difference between "find" and "children"

Comment: It's on the docs. `children` only works on **immediate** children and `find` on **all** children.

Comment: u looking for something like $("#container_svg_SeriesGroup_0").children().not('defs')

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
  $('#container_svg_SeriesGroup_0 > :not(defs)');
```